# Unable to fetch the array converted data from object

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, object

I have a object response type

```
    FirstGivingCreditCardDonationResponse Object ( [transactionId:FirstGivingCreditCardDonationResponse:private] => a-10d28597b9dc524bae6a02 
[rawResponse:FirstGivingCreditCardDonationResponse:private] => a-10d28597b9dc524bae6a020 
[responseCode:FirstGivingCreditCardDonationResponse:private] => 201 )
```

After converting into array it becomes

```
Array ( [FirstGivingCreditCardDonationResponsetransactionId] => a-b15ed981602d994d87718e [FirstGivingCreditCardDonationResponserawResponse] => a-b15ed981602d994d87718e0 [FirstGivingCreditCardDonationResponseresponseCode] => 201 )
```

When I want these values from array it shows

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: FirstGivingCreditCardDonationResponseresponseCode

Filename: controllers/campaign.php

Line Number: 132
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably you are using this class here: https://github.com/firstgiving/FirstGiving-PHP-SDK/blob/master/src/FirstGivingCreditCardDonationResponse.php

I wouldn't convert the object into an array, just access its private properties via the public methods:

```
$ResponseObject::getTransactionID();
$ResponseObject::getRawResponse();
$ResponseObject::getResponseCode();
```

You may need to include that header to define the Class in order to work with it

Comment: Where do i get $ResponseObject ?

Comment: Sorry, `$ResponseObject` was just assumed as the PHP variable you assign the object to when you receive it as a response. I'd need a bit more context to really help you more there

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: Campaign::$transactionId

Filename: firstgiving/FirstGivingCreditCardDonationResponse.php

Line Number: 42

Comment: Have you included that SDK? The README on that project has more information on how to use their API https://github.com/firstgiving/FirstGiving-PHP-SDK/blob/master/README

Comment: `$firstGivingCreditCardDonationResponse = $firstGivingApiClient->makeCreditCardDonation($donation, $creditCardPayment, $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);` is the line where you get your response object and so you can then access the data using the methods above

Comment: @require_once dir(__DIR__).APPPATH.'libraries/firstgiving/FirstGivingAPIClient'.EXT;

Comment: well, i have use a foreach loop to retrive all the required data from the object.Thank you GroovyCarrot :)

Comment: Glad you sussed it out :)